# SQL pivot columns based on condition

Tags: sql, pivot

I am new to SQL and am facing an issue with transposing / pivoting a table.
Lets assume I have the following table:

```
| ID | Coordinate | Name | Value | Group_Sequence | <p>
| 1 | ABC | John | 123 | 1 |
| 2 | DEF | Mary | 345 | 1 |
| 3 | DEF | Joseph | 456 | 2 |
```

I would like to turn it into something like the following:

```
| Coordinate | Name1 | Value1 | Name2 | Value2 |
| ABC | John | 123 | (null) | (null) |
| DEF | Mary | 345 | Joseph | 456 |
```

Basically, I would like to have one row per Coordinate. Every time a Coordinate has more than one entry, the Name and Value would be pivoted to the initial Coordinate where Group_Sequence=1.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` to enumerate the values and then aggregate:

```
select coordinate,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then name end) as name_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then value end) as value_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then name end) as name_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then value end) as value_2
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by coordinate order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by coordinate;
```